# How to configure bitcoind to wait for X confirmations to make the payment submitted

Tags: bitcoind, confirmations, ecommerce

I'm using bitcoind for an ecommerce website. Walletnotify setting in bitcoin.conf only fires twice (once the payment appears on the network and then when the payment is confimed the first time by a block).

The issue is that i need to set the number of confirmations before the payment is submitted. Could you please give me some help on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `listunspent` RPC command. It takes a parameter which allows you to filter out UTXOs which have less than `X` confirmations.

Example (from the manpage):

```
bitcoin-cli listunspent 6 9999999 "[\"bc1INVALIDq09vm5lfy0j5reeulh4x5752q25uqqvz34hufd\",\"bc1INVALIDq02ad21edsxd23d32dfgqqsz4vv4nmtfzuklhy3\"]"
```